# Can a .bat file be used to edit group policy?

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, wsus

I'm setting up a wsus for a local college, and I'm looking into ways that are more effect for updating the Group policy on the computers so that they update via the wsus. Manually doing every one is quite a pain. Also, these will be client computers, so I'll need a .bat to revert to default when they're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see the file you linked. However all settings/changes in group policy are stored in registry so you can make a snapshot of registry before and after modifying the group policy, comparing them and finding the necessary keys. In this way you can use a .reg file to apply change across all computers.

A useful tool: [regshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/)

Another option is to use [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the change made by group policy(mmc.exe) and find the corresponding keys.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11852388/

Comment: Would it work across multiple operating systems? If I were to use the regshot registry file on both Windows 10 and Vista, would it mess either of them up?